Почему через nginx не отображается фото сайта Django
У меня сайт, работающий в связке nginx + uWSGI + Django. Я разбил nginx на два файла: nginx.conf и default.conf. Почему-то nginx не отдает медиа файлы (фотографии сайта), расположенные в папке /Users/nnhufg/Desktop/CORGIFUME/brand_site/media/!ALL_IMAGES.
nginx.conf
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    include /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    server_tokens off;
    include /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/default.conf; 
}

default.conf
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-CSRFToken $cookie_csrftoken;
    }
    
    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /Users/nnhufg/Desktop/CORGIFUME/brand_site/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /Users/nnhufg/Desktop/CORGIFUME/brand_site/media/;
    }
}

Ошибка следующего характера в логах:
>2024/06/24 00:52:23 [error] 35728#0: *99 open() "/Users/nnhufg/Desktop/CORGIFUME/brand_site/media/!ALL_IMAGES/PACO_RABANNE_1_MILLION_5МЛ_1_cqo7lcK.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /media/!ALL_IMAGES/PACO_RABANNE_1_MILLION_5%D0%9C%D0%9B_1_cqo7lcK.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/main/catalog"

Полагаю, что ошибка в правах доступа.
ps aux | grep nginx

nobody           35728   0.0  0.0 411303184    928   ??  S    11:19PM   0:00.09 nginx: worker process
root             35727   0.0  0.0 410740752    400   ??  Ss   11:19PM   0:00.00 nginx: master process nginx
nnhufg           75192   0.0  0.0 410733264   1456 s001  S+   12:59AM   0:00.00 grep nginx

Права доступа к папке media:
nnhufg@MacBook-Air-Artem nginx % ls -ld /Users/nnhufg/Desktop/CORGIFUME/brand_site/media/
drwxr-xr-x  3 nobody  nobody  96 Jun 10 17:05 /Users/nnhufg/Desktop/CORGIFUME/brand_site/media/

Запутался и не понимаю как отобразить фотки через nginx.

Доступы должны быть и у всех родительских каталогов. А если у вас macOS, то у меня очень сильное подозрение, что нет доступа как минимум к каталогу Desktop

Хотя если файлы из staticfiles всё-таки работают (по крайней мере вы не стали жаловаться на них вопросе), значит, возможно, доступ к каталогу Desktop всё-таки есть — ну тогда как минимум стоит проверить доступ к подкаталогу !ALL_IMAGES что ли (и перепроверить, создаёт ли Django подкаталоги сразу с нужными доступами)

@andreymal спасибо, решил проблему, просто перезапустив компьютер...
